# psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

The error adds:      LINE 5      ORDER BY bk_title
^

Initially, the search filter works well with the table only showing the searched term. But when we added the "ORDER BY bk_title", the search suddenly does not work and puts up the error.

Here is our full code on that part:

```
def updatebooks_allbooks_list_atoz(pathname, searchterm):
if pathname == '/' or '/books':
    
    sql = """ SELECT bk_title, bk_author, genre_name, bk_pub_yr, bk_inv_count, bk_id
            FROM books
                INNER JOIN genres on books.genre_id = genres.genre_id
            WHERE NOT bk_delete_ind
            ORDER BY bk_title
    """
    val = []
    cols = ["Title", "Author", "Genre","Publication Year","Stock Quantity","Book ID"]
    

    if searchterm:
        sql += """ AND bk_title ILIKE %s"""
        val += [f"%{searchterm}%"]
        
    books_allbooks_atoz = db.querydatafromdatabase(sql,val,cols)
    
    if books_allbooks_atoz.shape[0]:
        buttons = []
        for bk_id in books_allbooks_atoz['Book ID']:
            buttons += [
                html.Div(
                    dbc.Button('View/Edit/Delete', href=f"/books/books_profile?mode=edit&id={bk_id}",
                        size='sm', color='dark', ),
                        style={'text-align': 'center'}
                )
            ]
        
        books_allbooks_atoz['Action'] = buttons
        books_allbooks_atoz.drop('Book ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
        books_allbooks_table_atoz = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(books_allbooks_atoz, striped=True, bordered=True, hover=True, size='sm', dark=False,)
        
        return [books_allbooks_table_atoz]
    
    else:
        return ["There are no records that match the search term."]

else:
    raise PreventUpdate
```

We now don't know if why the search does not work when we just added the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Can you show us the final sql variable contents (the one which is executed.)

Comment: It looks like the ORDER BY is placed in the middle of the WHERE clause, between conditions.

Comment: Before adding the `order by` your conditions were concatenated to the `where` clause. Now that `order by` is at the end, you're adding conditions to `order by`, first one ending up as `bk_title and bk_title ilike ...` which causes the error. Remove the `order by` from the initial `sql` variable value and add it *after* you're done filling out the `where` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the `order by` your conditions were concatenated to the `where` clause. Now that `order by` is at the end of your query text in `sql` variable, later concatenation adds stuff to `order by` instead of the `where` section, first one ending up as `bk_title and bk_title ilike ...` which causes the error.

Given a `searchterm='The Lord of The Rings'` it used to be

```sql
SELECT bk_title, bk_author, genre_name, bk_pub_yr, bk_inv_count, bk_id
FROM books INNER JOIN genres on books.genre_id = genres.genre_id
WHERE NOT bk_delete_ind AND bk_title ILIKE '%The Lord of The Rings%'
```

now it ends up as:

```sql
SELECT bk_title, bk_author, genre_name, bk_pub_yr, bk_inv_count, bk_id
FROM books INNER JOIN genres on books.genre_id = genres.genre_id
WHERE NOT bk_delete_ind
ORDER BY bk_title AND bk_title ILIKE '%The Lord of The Rings%'; --invalid
         ^        ^   ^
         varchar  ^   (varchar ILIKE text) evaluates to boolean
                  ^   
                  "AND" requires a boolean to the left and right
                  it is now getting varchar on the left and boolean on the right
```

and you probably wanted

```sql
SELECT bk_title, bk_author, genre_name, bk_pub_yr, bk_inv_count, bk_id
FROM books INNER JOIN genres on books.genre_id = genres.genre_id
WHERE NOT bk_delete_ind AND bk_title ILIKE '%The Lord of The Rings%' 
ORDER BY bk_title
```

Remove the `order by` from the initial `sql` variable value and add it *after* you're done filling out the where conditions.

```python
def updatebooks_allbooks_list_atoz(pathname, searchterm):
if pathname == '/' or '/books':
    
    sql = """ SELECT bk_title, bk_author, genre_name, bk_pub_yr, bk_inv_count, bk_id
            FROM books
                INNER JOIN genres on books.genre_id = genres.genre_id
            WHERE NOT bk_delete_ind """ #remove ORDER BY here
    val = []
    cols = ["Title", "Author", "Genre","Publication Year","Stock Quantity","Book ID"]
    

    if searchterm:
        sql += """ AND bk_title ILIKE %s"""
        val += [f"%{searchterm}%"]
    
    sql += """ ORDER BY bk_title """ #add ORDER BY here
    books_allbooks_atoz = db.querydatafromdatabase(sql,val,cols)

    #...
```

Comment: Now the error says:

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "AND"
LINE 6:       AND bk_title ILIKE '%yre%'

Comment: Can you edit your question and add show exactly what you changed and ran to get this error?

Comment: I just followed what you said: removed the `order by` statement in the first SQL variable value and added `sql += """ ORDER BY bk_title """` after the `if searchterm` instead. Now, I tried using the search feature again by typing yre (hence the %yre% statement in the error), and the new error shows up.

Btw, thank you so much for keeping up with this!! Highly appreciated!!

Comment: @BroLee the reason I ask is that unless you paste and show 1:1 exactly what you run and the *full* error message you got, I can only guess what happened. The error message is clearly saying your new query has a syntax problem, so something is likely misplaced.